# pwd doesn't work in windows when I include the git bash command line?

Tags: linux, windows, git, bash, pwd

I add the bin of git bash into my path in windows7 for the purpose of using linux command in windows. Other commands like ls, mkdir work fine but when I run "pwd" windows can't execute it. I found there is no pwd.exe in the bin directory. So I want to ask where I could download this file or if there is any better way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `pwd` is a bash built-in command. You can get it as a separate program in [GnuWin CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Answer (score 0):

in windows de equivalent command for pwd is path. Change pwd with path

Comment: path only shows the path variables not the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

A better way of using linux commands on windows is using Cygwin. It will not only allow you to run pwd and other linux commands but it will also make your windows command line as powerful as the linux terminal.

Check out the link below:
https://www.cygwin.com

Comment: I tried it but when I run Aptana,the terminal in it is the Cygwin terminal but not the one like windows and it's quite troublesome to change its start-up directory to the project dirctory

Comment: @CheuckKwanLee I could try to help you if you can elaborate on what you want to accomplish. In case you are learning development, just dump windows and switch to linux (ubuntu).

Comment: @ Ankit Goel I just want to use some frequent used linux command line in windows because I am doing ROR things in windows. If I use Cygwin, it would change the terminal in Aptana to behave like the terminal of Cygwin which would shows in linux style(using home,user...) which is not easy to find file in windows' drives. The reason why I don't use ubuntu is for the convenience of using Aptana in windows. So I'm looking for some way to do so.

Comment: @CheuckKwanLee Well, don't pick an OS because of an IDE. There are plenty of IDEs. If you would like to work on serverside it's better that you switch to linux.

Answer (score 0):

For **Command Prompt** in windows which is equivalent of **Terminal**, you can use `cd ,` instead of `pwd`... and `dir` instead of `ls`.